# Draw outside the screen edges when using FitViewport and OrthographicCamera

Tags: java, libgdx, viewport

**TLDR;** Using FitViewport and OrthographicCamera. Want to draw outside the screen edges (not the viewport edges!) without losing the automatic resizing of the objects as well as the beautifully centered origin. How?

---

I'm developing a game in which everything is centered (so the origin of the coordinate system should be in the exact center). There should be balls shooting from the outside of the world through the origin to the outside of the world on the other side, like this: [image: Terrible drawing of how I imagine the game to be]

I'm using the following - simplified - code:

```
// Skipping the package name and imports...

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport viewport;
    private ShapeRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        this.viewport = new FitViewport(1080, 1920, camera);
        this.viewport.apply();
        this.renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        this.renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        this.renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

        // For illustrating purposes
        this.renderer.setColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1);
        this.renderer.rect(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, -Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        this.renderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        // Gets drawn perfectly in center
        this.renderer.circle(0, 0, 100);
        // Gets drawn somewhere else where it does not belong
        this.renderer.circle(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, -Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 100, 100); 

        this.renderer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        this.renderer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        this.viewport.update(width, height);
    }

}
```

...which produces this result:

[image: Picture of how the game actually is]

---

**My question is:** How do I draw to the very outside of the edge while still maintaining the automatic resizing of any drawn objects to fit the device's resolution as well as the centered origin?

Comment: What do you men by draw outside the screen edges? Are you mixing up the terms screen and viewport in your first sentence?

Comment: Just like in the picture I've drawn the balls should be drawn outside the edges of the screen first and fly in. More specifically, I need a coordinate which lays exactly on the screen edge.